# Similar random number generation in python and c++ but getting different output

Tags: python, c++, random, random-seed

I have two functions, in c++ and python, that determine how many times an event with a certain probability will occur over a number of rolls.

Python version:

```
def get_loot(rolls):
    drops = 0

    for i in range(rolls):
        # getting a random float with 2 decimal places
        roll = random.randint(0, 10000) / 100
        if roll < 0.04:
            drops += 1

    return drops

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(get_loot(1000000))
```

Python output:

```
371
396
392
406
384
392
380
411
393
434
```

c++ version:

```
int get_drops(int rolls){
    int drops = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rolls; i++){
        // getting a random float with 2 decimal places
        float roll = (rand() % 10000)/100.0f;
        if (roll < 0.04){
            drops++;
        }
    }
    return drops;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        cout << get_drops(1000000) << "\n";
    }
}
```

c++ output:

```
602
626
579
589
567
620
603
608
594
610
626
```

The cood looks identical (at least to me). Both functions simulate an occurence of an event with a probablilty of 0.04 over 1,000,000 rolls. However the output of the python version is about 30% lower than that of the c++ version. How are these two versions different and why do they have different outputs?

Comment: I think the use of modulo skews your distribution. rand() produces 32767 values, the modulo creates a bias for the first 2767 values, they appear 33% more often and you don't get the same uniform distribution as with python. Modulo should not be used in random number generation.

Comment: Interesting! All tutorials on c++ RNG use the modulo to generate a number within a specific range.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, it is not correct to say you have simulated an event with a probability of 0.04, because `(rand() % 10000)/100.0f` can result in values in the hundreds, but 0.04 is the threshold. The expected value can be calculated as `0.04 * 1,000,000 = 40,000`, meaning you should get a "success" 40,000 times over 1,000,000 trials.

Comment: Include <random> and use Merseine twister, std::random_device, and uniform distribution: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Since the expected number of drops is (4/10001)*1000000 = 400, you should have asked why the the C results, around 50% higher, are so wrong.  (I checked to make sure that 4/100 < .04 is false, so the only ints that count are the 4 in {0, 1, 2, 3}.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ [rand()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) "Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX."

`RAND_MAX` is "is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767 on any standard library implementation."

Let's set `RAND_MAX` at 32,767.

When calculating [0, 32767) % 10000 the random number generation is skewed.

The values 0-2,767 all occur 4 times in the range (% 10000)->

| Value | Calculation | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 % 10000 | 1 |
| 10001 | 10001 % 10000 | 1 |
| 20001 | 20001 % 10000 | 1 |
| 30001 | 30001 % 10000 | 1 |

Where as the values 2,768-9,999 occur only 3 times in the range (% 10000) ->

| Value | Calculation | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2768 | 2768 % 10000 | 2768 |
| 12768 | 12768 % 10000 | 2768 |
| 22768 | 22768 % 10000 | 2768 |

This makes the values 0-2767 25% more likely to occur than the values 2768-9,999 (assuming `rand()` does, in fact, produce an even distribution between 0 and RAND_MAX).

---

Python on the other hand using [randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) produces an even distribution between start and end as `randint` is an "Alias for randrange(a, b+1)"

And [randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) (in python 3.2 and newer) will produce evenly distributed values:

> Changed in version 3.2: randrange() is more sophisticated about producing equally distributed values. Formerly it used a style like int(random()*n) which could produce slightly uneven distributions.

---

There are several approaches to generating random numbers in C++. Something perhaps the most similar to `python` would be to use a Mersenne Twister Engine (which is the same as python if with some differences).

Via [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) with [`mt19937`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>


int get_drops(int rolls) {
    std::mt19937 e{
            static_cast<unsigned int> (
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
            )
    };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d{0, 9999};
    int drops = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rolls; i++) {
        float roll = d(e) / 100.0f;
        if (roll < 0.04) {
            drops++;
        }
    }
    return drops;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        std::cout << get_drops(1000000) << "\n";
    }
}
```

It is notable that the underlying implementation of the two engines as well as seeding and distribution are all slightly different, however, this will be much closer to python.

---

Alternatively as [Matthias Fripp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332022/similar-random-number-generation-in-python-and-c-but-getting-different-output/68332092#comment120766511_68332092) suggests scaling up rand and dividing by `RAND_MAX`:

```cpp
int get_drops(int rolls) {
    int drops = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rolls; i++) {
        float roll = (10000 * rand() / RAND_MAX) / 100.0f;
        if (roll < 0.04) {
            drops++;
        }
    }
    return drops;
}
```

This is also much closer to the python output (again with some differences in the way random numbers are generated in the underlying implementations).

Answer (score 3):

The results are skewed because `rand() % 10000` is not the correct way to achieve a uniform distribution. (See also [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) by Stephan T. Lavavej.) In modern C++, prefer the [pseudo-random number generation library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) provided in header `<random>`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int get_drops(int rolls)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen{ rd() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis{ 0.0, 100.0 };
    int drops{ 0 };
    for(int roll{ 0 }; roll < rolls; ++roll)
    {
        if (dis(gen) < 0.04)
        {
            ++drops;
        }
    }

    return drops;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << get_drops(1000000) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Both languages use different pseudo-random generators. If you would like to unify the performance, you might want to deterministically generate your own pseudo-random values.

Here is how it should look like in Python:

```
SEED = 101
TOP = 999
class my_random(object):
    def seed(self, a=SEED):
        """Seeds a deterministic value that should behave the same irrespectively of the coding language"""
        self.seedval = a
    def random(self):
        """generates and returns the random number based on the seed"""
        self.seedval = (self.seedval * SEED) % TOP
        return self.seedval

instance = my_random(SEED)
read_seed = instance.seed
read_random = instance.random()
```

However, in C++, it should become:

```cpp
const int SEED = 101;
const int TOP = 9999;
class myRandom(){
    int seedval;
    public int random();
    myRandom(int a=SEED){
        this.seedval = a;
    }
    int random(){
        this.seedval = (this.seedval * SEED) % TOP;
        return this.seedval;
    }
    int seed(){
        return this.seedval;
    }
}
instance = myRandom(SEED);
readSeed = instance.seed;
readRandom = instance.random();
```